# Centered background + full page container

Tags: html, css

I want to put a background (width = 1250px) centered on page, but the container, should have the width of browser

This center the background:

```
#container{margin:0 auto;background:#000 url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;width:1250px;;}
```

And this set the width of container = the browser

```
#container{margin:0 auto;background:#000 url("../../../images/background.jpg") no-repeat;width:100%;position:relative;}
```

How to get centered background image and full page container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your background rule to this:

```
background:#000 url(images/background.jpg) center center no-repeat;
```

Or if you want to center it at the top of the page, do this:

```
background:#000 url(images/background.jpg) center top no-repeat;
```

Then you can remove the `margin: 0 auto` because it's useless with a width of 100%.

Comment: The `margin:0 auto;` is a typo (ctrl c + ctr v issue =D). I never thought that `center center` would be useful some time, so I ended up dropping the solution without testing.

Answer (score 2):

basic CSS

```
background: #000 url(../../../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Note: you don't need quotes in the css. In fact, in some instances there may be issues when you use quotes.